# elisp: generate LaTeX PDF document

Tags: pdf, emacs, latex, elisp

I trying to completely automatize sending job applications. First step, to put the name of the company in a letter. It almost works, but it is stuck because it asks what command to use. Reading the documentation, I thought it could be disabled by a prefix argument, but I got something wrong. Also, it doesn't need to flash by visually, it could be done completely as a background process. I'll paste the code and you'll understand immediately:

(Oh, I'm using LaTeX/P mode in emacs - the goal is to not only update the .tex but also the .pdf file)

```
(defun edit-letter (comp-name)
  (let ((path "~/work/letter/comp"))
    (edit-letter-file-path comp-name (concat path "/eng/letter.tex")) 
    (edit-letter-file-path comp-name (concat path "/swe/brev.tex")) ))

(defun edit-letter-file-path (company-name file-path)
  (find-file file-path)
  (goto-line 14)
  (kill-line)
  (insert (format "\\textbf{To %s}\n" company-name))
  (setq current-prefix-arg nil)
  (call-interactively 'TeX-command-master) ; asks what command
  (kill-buffer) ) ; doesn't work

(edit-letter "Digital Power Now")
```

Comment: OK, solved it like this. Not much but it works. Concluding the second function above: `(shell-command (concat "pdflatex --output-directory ~/work/letter/comp " file-path))`

Answer (score 2):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you're after, but if you want to use AucTeX to call a LaTeX/PDFTex/BibTex process without getting prompted for the command name, you can use this:

```lisp
(TeX-command "LaTeX" 'TeX-master-file)
```

Try this in place of `(call-interactively 'TeX-command-master)` above. When you're using LaTeX/P "LaTeX" really means pdflatex.

Comment: This was so long ago so I've forgotten the details. But I managed to solve it (see my comment above). Anyway, thanks for the effort and the hint :)

Comment: I didn't realize how old your question was, I was just browsing unanswered questions and saw it. I was just working with this code today for a project so it was fresh on my mind!

Comment: No, in general, of course it is 100% correct to answer any question, regardless of time. If you're into Emacs and (E)Lisp, you can check out the end result [here](http://user.it.uu.se/~embe8573/auto-work.el).